# populate one edit text based on input of another android

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create an android calculator, i want some of the edit text fields to populate based on the input of another, any help appreciated, so far i can change it with a button click

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {                                          
EditText e1 = findViewById(R.id.CostPriceNum);                           
EditText e2 = findViewById(R.id.SalePriceNum);                           
EditText e3 = findViewById(R.id.postageCost);                            
//double num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());               
//double num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());               
//double num3 = Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());               

double num1 = Double.parseDouble("0" + e1.getText().toString());         
double num2 = Double.parseDouble("0" + e2.getText().toString());         
double num3 = Double.parseDouble("0" + e3.getText().toString());         

EditText e4 = findViewById(R.id.ebayFeeNum);                             
double sum = num2/10 ;                                                   
e4.setText(Double.toString(sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text of one editText based on another editText by using an
addTextChangedListener. Below you can find an example.

```
public class Demo1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText edt1;
private EditText edt2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo1);
    hookButtons();
}

private void hookButtons() {

    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_1);
    edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_2);


    edt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            edt2.setText(s.toString());
        }
    });
}}
```

Below is the layout of the above activity (demo1.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Change"
    />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="---"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="---"/>

</LinearLayout>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Result"
    /></LinearLayout>
```

Also, don't forget to add this activity to the manifest.